# Can't get inner text of a attribute element

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

As the title says, i'm trying to get the inner text of an attribute element.

Essentially, I can get the attribute href from it, but when using inner text on a   element, it returns a null value.

Is there some way around this issue? I'm not sure what is causing it .

```
        brand = item.querySelector("div>div>div>div>div>div>a").innerText;
```

Is the code in question,

and what I'm trying to get the value of.

```
<a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=DChcSEwjayYr5tZ7pAhXDNSsKHZ2bBPMYABAEGgJzZg&amp;sig=AOD64_0aFHVw25okBXOfPR5PjAv2EgobTw&amp;ctype=5&amp;q=&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiDg4b5tZ7pAhXDyzgGHU-SAV8Qg-UECLgD&amp;adurl=" rel="noopener" target="_blank" class="shntl hy2WroIfzrX__merchant-name">Yin Yam - Asian Grocery</a>
```

also tried this.

```
          brand = item.querySelector("div>div>div>div>div>div>a").textContent;
```

Comment: Have you tried usong `textContent` instead of `innerText`? The latter may be affected by the rendered formatting of the text https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks!

Comment: It sounds like it's not finding it. Try something like `a[class*="merchant-name"]`.

Comment: @pguardiario Feel free to answer question, as this solved the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          brand = item.querySelector("div>div>div>div>div>div>a[class*='merchant-name']").innerText;
```

This answer, based on a comment below the question, worked like a charm :)